# Silverlight 4 dropdown control

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to create a drop down control that is made up of a text box a button and a treeview control. I can not really find any tutorials on how to create a custom drop down control. I did find a user control that drops down a treeview control (vectorlight), but I want to implement my own custom drop down control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use a popup control like so

```
  <Popup Name="popupTask" IsOpen="False">
    <Border BorderThickness=".5" CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White">
      <sdk:TreeView Grid.Row="1" Height="300" Width="270" Name="treeViewTasks" VerticalAlignment="Top"  SelectedItemChanged="treeViewTasks_SelectedItemChanged" />
    </Border>
  </Popup>
```

From the code behind
      if (popupTask.IsOpen)
      {
        popupTask.IsOpen = false;
      }
      else
      {
        popupTask.VerticalOffset = 25;
        popupTask.HorizontalOffset = 0; 
        popupTask.IsOpen = true;
      }

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at this open source control:

http://sl4popupmenu.codeplex.com

Its quite flexible and easy to implement and supports any derivative of the ItemsControl which includes the TreeView.